# How to run client and server code at the same time

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I have client code which is in the client folder. I have done yarn build to create the production build.

I also have a server which holds the API end points how do I run them concurrently using the production of the client code.

Server Package.json:

```
  "scripts": {
    "client-install": "npm install --prefix client",
    "start": "node server.js",
    "server": "nodemon server.js",
    "client": "npm start --prefix client",
    "dev": "concurrently \"npm run server\" \"npm run client\"",
    "prod": "NODE_ENV=production concurrently \"npm run server\" \"npm run client\""
  },
```

server.js:

```
// Routes
app.use("/api/users", users);

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;

app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Server up and running on port ${PORT} !`));
```

client package.json:

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "proxy": "http://localhost:5000",
```

Comment: your project running fine in development env right ???

Comment: @PrakashKarena yes

Comment: You need to create a fall back route that loads the generated index.html anytime any other routes aren’t matched. Usually this is done using express sendFile.

Comment: Your best bet would be to open a second terminal and run one from each.  Alternatively, you could run them simultaneously using [concurrently](https://github.com/kimmobrunfeldt/concurrently) or simply separating the two commands with an `&` if you're using bash, but that's more fragile.

Comment: @AlexanderNied when i run concurrently i cant call the apis. i get proxy problems

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you do `yarn build` for client prod, you generate some index.html with js, let's say in client/build folder (you can adjust path for your needs). Therefore you don't need `npm run client`, you just have to serve html files. It's possible to add handler in `server.js` after all routes defined, like this

```
if (['production'].includes(process.env.NODE_ENV)) {
  app.use(express.static('client/build'));

  const path = require('path');
  app.get('*', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.resolve('client', 'build', 'index.html'));
  });
}
```

One last step is to update script in `package.json` file the following way

```
"prod": "NODE_ENV=production node server.js"
```

That's it

Answer (score 1):

you can add default fallback for your front end like

```
   if(process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'){
        const path  =  require('path');
        app.use(express.static('client/build'));
        app.get('/*',(req,res)=>{ 
            res.sendfile(path.resolve(__dirname,'../client','build','index.html')); // change as per your index.html 
        })
    }
```

Comment: try this out if you still have any problem then let me know

Comment: you can refer my project which is also running concurrently https://github.com/karenaprakash/final-project.git

Comment: where exactly do i put this? where in the client code.

Comment: in  your server you need to add this code and please have a look into my project package.json file and match with yours

Comment: the if statement does not run

Comment: yes sorry the if statement works , but my client cant reach the server still. do u have discord or something? i can screenshare

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206491/discussion-between-ayush-parikh-and-prakash-karena).